# How can i sum up multiple inputs in one when using a submodel?

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, tree, recurrent-neural-network

I wrote a custom Tree-RNN-CELL that can handle several different inputs when they are provided as a tuple.

```
...
treeCell3_1 = TreeRNNCell(units=encodingBitLength, num_children=2)
RNNC = layers.RNN(treeCell3_1, return_state=True, return_sequences=True)
h_c_batch, h, c = RNNC(
    inputs=(h_batch2_1, c_batch2_1, h_batch2_2, c_batch2_2))
```

This is working fine, but now I wanted to put it together in a submodel, so that i can sum the 4 lines up in 2 lines and to have a better overview ( the tree gets big so its worth it)

```
class TreeCellModel(tf.keras.Model):

    def __init__(self, units, num_children):
        super().__init__()
        self.units = units
        self.num_children = num_children
        self.treeCell = TreeRNNCell(units=units, num_children=num_children)
        self.treeRNN = layers.RNN(self.treeCell, return_state=True, return_sequences=True)

    def call(self, inputs, **kwargs):

        h_c_batch, h, c = self.treeRNN(inputs=(inputs))
        h_batch, c_batch = AddCellStatesLayer(units=self.units)(h_c_batch)

        return h_batch, c_batch

treeCell2_1 = TreeCellModel(units=encodingBitLength, num_children=2)
h_batch2_1, c_batch2_1 = treeCell1_1(inputs=(h_batch1_1, c_batch1_1, h_batch1_2, c_batch1_2))
```

But now i get this error:
ValueError: Layer rnn expects 1 input(s), but it received 4 input tensors. Inputs received: [<tf.Tensor 'h_batch1_1' shape=(1, 5, 19) dtype=float32>, <tf.Tensor 'c_batch1_1' shape=(1, 5, 19) dtype=float32>, <tf.Tensor 'h_batch1_2' shape=(1, 5, 19) dtype=float32>, <tf.Tensor 'c_batch1_2' shape=(1, 5, 19) dtype=float32>]

I checked the error already, and normally it gets fixed when using a tuple around the inputs. But thats what I'm already doing. I also doublechecked by outputting the type of "inputs" and it is a tuple.

Help please.

Comment: PS: It seems you're creating a layer inside the `call` of your model? This doesn't sound ok.

Comment: Hey, yes that is from before it was a submodel. i will change that, after I fixed the first issue.

Comment: Hmm, I think I didn't read your question well. Did you notice you are defining `treeCell2_1` and calling a different `treeCell1_1`?

Comment: Okay, and i thought the new numeration would be better. Wow, thank you so much. It works now. in the treecell 1_1, it really does expect only one input so no wonder it didn't work. You're the best!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`RNN` is expecting "one" input, then you must give it "one" input. The implementation of your cell will probably not matter.

You can change your code to join the 4 tensors together and separate them inside your cell. This is possible because all your tensors have the same shape.

You could use a:

```
joined_inputs = layers.Lambda(lambda x: keras.backend.stack(x, axis=-1))([input1, input2, input3, input4])
```

Then your cell should be able to separate the inputs:

```
def call(self, inputTensor .....):
    inputs = [inputTensor[:,:,:,i] for i in range(4)]

    ....
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for your answer.
But why does it work in the first example with a tuple as input, but not when using it in the submodel? 

I exchanged the cell inside the RNN, so it even expects several inputs.